# ChartJS looping string issue

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to use chart.JS in order to render dynamicaly charts in my django app

I am trying to generate dynamic datasets based on the number of users.
I used the following code to loop on my users:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: endpoint,
  success: function(data){
    console.log(data)
    //Labels comming from wevsite.views//
    team = data.team_list
    info_data = data.info_process_data

    var datasetValue = [];
    var name = team
    var count = name.length;
    for (var j=0; j<count; j++) {
        datasetValue[j] = {
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(220,220,220,0.5)',
            label : name[j],
            data : info_data,
        };
    }
    var looped_data = JSON.stringify(datasetValue);

    var ctx = document.getElementById("mainGraph").getContext('2d');

      var info_process = new Chart(ctx2,{
      type: 'radar',
      data: {
        labels: labels_info,
        datasets: looped_array
            },
        options: {
           scale: {display: true,
                   ticks: {
                     beginAtZero: true,
     }
                  },
           responsive:true,
           maintainAspectRatio: true,
          }
    });
})
```

I get the error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot create property '_meta' on string. 
I guess because chartsJS does not accept string ..

How can I make it work ?

Thx you very much

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var info_process = new Chart(ctx,{`?

Comment: yes .Right wrong copy past .. but with no impact on my problem ..which come from here:var looped_data = JSON.stringify(datasetValue);